# What is an 'unupvote'?

Tags: support

I know of upvotes and downvotes, resulting in +10 or -2 of reputation.

But today I had 10 x 'unupvote'. What is that and when does it happen?

Comment: I suspect a user who upvoted you deleted his/her account.

Comment: Yeah, Takkat is right. Unfortunately -.-

Comment: Or maybe, after you edited an answer, a user revokes his upvote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An "unupvote" is when an upvote is removed. There are a number of reasons this may happen:

- A user decided to revoke their original upvote because they no longer think your post was useful
- The upvote was part of a series of upvotes made in quick succession by a single user over a short time, which got revoked as part of voter fraud reversal
- The upvote originally belonged to a user who got merged into a user who had already voted for you, thus cancelling the otherwise doubled vote.
- The upvote originally belonged to a user who got deleted, and thus all of their votes have become nulled.

In your situation (and numerous others in recent, one might say), there *have* been recent user deletions on the site, so a lot of upvotes might be seen as missing today.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - I assumed previously that user deletion has no impact, since (if done seriously) they made sense at the earlier time and should not be affected by later decision to quit from the community - but if that is not the case, I understand the reputation substraction.

Comment: By the way, who displeased Gigili? ;-)